# Minimizing geodesic on a convex surface

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, alexandrov-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

Let $\Sigma$ be a smooth convex surface in Euclidean 3-space
and $\gamma$ be a unit speed minimizing geodesic in $\Sigma$.
Assume that for some $a < b < c$, we have 
$$\gamma'(a)=\gamma'(b)=\gamma'(c).$$

Is it true that $\gamma'$ is constant on one of two intervals $[a,b]$ or $[b,c]$?

**Comments**

- This is a simplification-variation of an other question I heard from Dima Burago.
- It is not hard t construct an example of a minimizing geodesic such that $\gamma'(a)=\gamma'(b)$, but $\gamma'$ is not a constant on $[a,b]$. (See the example below.)
- I would be also interested in the analog for $n$ points.
- This paper: ["Total curvature..." by Barany, Kuperberg, Zamfirescu](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0301338) is relevant.
- Recently, in ["On the total curvature..." by Nina Lebedeva and me](http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.07911) we answered the original question of Dima Burago. The problem above remains open, likely the answer is "no".

**Example.** I will construct a convex polyhedron, but it is easy to smooth.
Consider polyhedron defined by 5 inequlaities: 
$$z\ge 0,\ \  |x+\alpha{\cdot}y|\le \alpha\  \ \text{and}\  \  z\pm\beta{\cdot}y\le \beta$$
and look at the minimizing geodesic between points $(0,1-\epsilon, \beta{\cdot}\epsilon)$ and $(0,-(1-\epsilon), \beta{\cdot}\epsilon)$. For appropriately chousen $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\epsilon$ this minimizing geodesic will pass through the faces in this order $$\{z+\beta{\cdot}y= \beta\},\ \ \{x+\alpha{\cdot}y= \alpha\},\ \  \{z=0\},\ \ \{x+\alpha{\cdot}y= -\alpha\},\ \ \{z-\beta{\cdot}y= \beta\}$$ 
and it will have the same velocity vector $(1,0,0)$ on both faces $\{z+\beta{\cdot}y= \beta\}$ and  $\{z-\beta{\cdot}y= \beta\}$.

Comment: My reaction to this is that this doesn't sound that hard *but* if you and Dmitri can't answer it, it's not likely I can either. Nice question, though. I will have to give it a try.

Comment: I realize that it should be just homework for me, but could you provide the details of the example with two points with the same velocity?

Comment: Presumably gluing your $[a,b]$ example to its reverse can only be realized on a nonconvex surface?

Comment: @Deane: I add the example.

Comment: I can see now that my initial reaction was correct. Nice question.

Answer (score 7):

Just to help visualize the example, if 
I have interpreted the description correctly, 
this is one view, for $\alpha=\beta=1$, and $\epsilon=\frac{1}{16}$.

[image: Polyhedron]

In this view, the $x$-axis is horizontal, the $z$-axis vertical.

**Addendum**. The shortest path (yellow) from $p_1$ to $p_2$ follows the face sequence (Bk, R, Bt, L, F).

[image: Unfolding]

 I tried to indicate (in the nearly invisible short dashed lines) the initial direction of the path
on the (mauve) Bk and F faces, in their planar unfoldings.  I should note that these initial
velocities are not exactly $(1,0,0)$, which presumably is only achieved by "appropriately chosen"
$\alpha, \beta, \epsilon$.

Comment: On the second diagram, the angles of rotations at $p_1$ and $p_2$ should be bit more than π/2. 

Comment: Awesome picture, as always.